# Induced graph of specific coreness

Tags: python, igraph

Is there a better way of having the induced sub-graph of a specific coreness than this code:

```
g= Graph.Erdos_Renyi(50, 0.3)
g.vs["coreness"]= g.coreness(mode=ALL)

def get_inducedGraph(g,k):
    ids=[]
    for v in g.vs:
        if v["coreness"] >= k:
            ids.append(v["id"])
    return g.induced_subgraph(ids)
```

The problem with this code is that it is slow for large graphs.

Comment: What exactly is slow?

Comment: More precisely, can you measure the time it takes to calculate `g.coreness()`? Theoretically, coreness calculation should be linear in the number of edges of the graph, so it shouldn't be slow for large graphs.